# Showing loading screen?

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, algorithm

I want to show a loading screen while my doubles, longitude and latitude, are 0. Currently, my dialog doesn't even show, and an error comes:

```
while(awesome.longitude == 0 && awesome.latitude == 0){

            Log.v(TAG, "In While");

            ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "",
                    "Fetching Location...Please wait. If this takes too long, try again.", true);

            dialog.show();

        }
```

Longitude and Latitude are variables in the class `RuchirLocation`, and `awesome` is an object of `RuchirLocation`

**The while loop goes through, but the dialog doesn't show. Then, after looping about 50 times, I get this error:**

```
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not read input channel file descriptors from parcel.
```

pointing at:

```
        ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "",
                "Fetching Location...Please wait. If this takes too long, try again.", true);
```

How can I fix this? I simply want to show a loading dialog while my variables are 0.

Thanks,

Ruchir

Answer (score 0):

The proper way is to show the dialog initially and as soon as you get the value of those variables then dismiss the progress dialog.

```
ProgressDialog pd;

if(awesome.longitude == 0 && awesome.latitude == 0){
    pd = new ProgressDialog(//context here);
    pd.setMessage("Loading...")
    pd.show();
}
```

And as soon as you get the value of those variables -

```
pd.dismiss();
```

Comment: How do I constantly check if the variable value changed then?

Comment: How will I know when to dismiss?

Comment: @Wukash I request updates for my location in a separate class, and store them in values. Then, I get the values from my main class. However,  I want   to show the dialog while the location is 0, because it takes some initial time to get the location update in the first place.

Comment: Then pass your object from which you call Dialog to the object that requests updates and call some method from there that will dismiss Dialog...

Comment: So when you receive the location update, you need to notify your activity to close to dialog or as Wukash mentioned, you could pass your pd reference to the class containing location updates and from there itself you can dismiss the dialog. But it would be better to pass the result to activity directly so that you know as soon as the updates arrive

Comment: Yeah that's what I said, to pass 'object from which you call pd', not pd itself :) Meaning activity or sth else, no clue what since OP didn't show enough code.